Clarification on Average Binary Encoding Method for Categorical Data in Machine Learning Models
There are lots of methods that represent converting categorical data into numerical data for various statistical tasks. However, most encoding methods, such as One-Hot encoding, create more dataset columns, making high-dimensional data.
Therefore, I introduce a method called Average Binary Encoding, which applies a binary data representation in the training model. The method is as follows:

Where |N| is the length of binary values in categorical data X, and B is the binary representation for categorical data X.
| Categorical data | Applied in Formula                                                                                     | Encoded data       |
| ---------------- | ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ | ------------------ |
| Male             | (0+1+0+0+1+1+0+1+0+1+1+0+0+0+0+1+0+1+1+0+1+1+0+0+0+1+1+0+0+1+0+1) ÷ 32                                 | 0.46875            |
| Female           | (0+1+0+0+0+1+1+0+0+1+1+0+0+1+0+1+0+1+1+0+1+1+0+1+0+1+1+0+0+0+0+1+0+1+1+0+1+1+0+0+0+1+1+0+0+1+0+1) ÷ 48 | 0.4791666666666667 |
| Yes              | (0+1+0+1+1+0+0+1+0+1+1+0+0+1+0+1+0+1+1+1+0+0+1+1) ÷ 24                                                 | 0.5416666666666666 |
| No               | (0+1+0+0+1+1+1+0+0+1+1+0+1+1+1+1) ÷16                                                                  | 0.625              |
| 1                | (0+0+1+1+0+0+0+1) ÷ 8                                                                                  | 0.375              |
| 0                | (0+0+1+1+0+0+0+0) ÷ 8                                                                                  | 0.25               |

For example,
The binary representation for categorical data “Male” is 01001101011000010110110001100101.
The length of that binary data is 32.
Therefore, using the formula, the encoded value is 0.46875.
I want to get more clarification on this encoding method to see if it works in statistical models.
Are there any specific considerations or limitations to encode categorical data?

When you encode categorical data as numeric, the distances between numbers are important. In this case you are applying a pretty arbitrary function that maps the inputs into [0,1]. Because this function is arbitrary, the distances between the outputs are arbitrary too, which will make it quite difficult to fit useful models.
